# Where can I find a TM/Answer Key for Jenney’s First Year Latin Text?

Tags: resource-request, teaching-method

I teach Latin using Jenney’s First Year Latin at a local school and it’s been cumbersome to do so without a TM/ answer key for the text and workbook.  Does anyone know where I can find a copy of the TM/answer key? Or can I pay someone for a copy?  Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm curious about this as well. If you end up finding it, please do let us know!